# PHP PDF code not working

Tags: php, pdf, localhost

I have a section where you can download work related PDFs. The code works in my localhost but not on the live site. Any ideas as to what happened?

```
<div id="resources">
<h1>Pilot Car Resources</h1>
<table style="width:400px" id="resourcesTable">
  <tr>
   <td>Kansas Handbook</td>
   <td><a href="?file=kansasHandbook.pdf">Download PDF File</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>GA Amber Light Application</td>
   <td><a href="?file=georgiaAmberLightApplication.pdf">Download PDF File</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

And the PHP

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET["file"]) && !empty($_GET["file"])) {
    $file    = $_GET["file"];
    $path    = "/resources/";
    $getFile = $path . $file;
    if (file_exists($getFile)) {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . urlencode(basename($getFile)));
        // header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($getFile));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($getFile);
        exit;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: What happens when you try to download one?

Comment: The page refreshes and just scrolls back to the top. Like clicking a link with a "#" in the href.

Comment: Hmm, are files really served from `/resources/` at the root of the file system? I expect you have a security issue here too: try fetching `?file=../etc/passwd` or some other sensitive file (it's probably a good thing if it doesn't work currently!).

Comment: It sounds that the `$_GET['file']` clause is being ignored - maybe do some debugging to see if the code inside the `if` block is being run.

Comment: Kinda new to this still. How do I debug and all that?

Comment: To be clear on my directories:

The pdf script is in scripts/php/downloadPDF.php

and the pdf files are in /resources/

Comment: Debugging, in its simplest form: put `echo 1; exit();` where you want to see if execution reaches. Change the number if you use several at the same time. Sprinkle liberally around your code, then restore from version control once you've found where the problem is. I suspect PDF files don't exist or have incorrect permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1

You start at

http://jollyrogerpcs.com/index.php

Hyperlinks on your page are to href="file/?kansasHandbook.pdf"

So you do a file request to

http://jollyrogerpcs.com/index.php?file=kansasHandbook.pdf

$_GET['file'] is ignored and the html from http://jollyrogerpcs.com/index.php is delivered to the browser. This is why your page refreshes when you click the download pdf link.

Change you links to absolute links that reference downloadPDF.php AND the file get var.

E.G

http://jollyrogerpcs.com/scripts/php/downloadPDF.php?file=/kansasHandbook.pdf

Problem 2

It's hard to tell without seeing more code, but you seem have have another path related issue in downloadPDF.php. When you do the GET request to that url, your $getFile will be '/resources/kansasHandbook.pdf'. I believe that readfile() will try to search for the PDF in http://jollyrogerpcs.com/scripts/php/resources/kansasHandbook.pdf.

You can troubleshoot this by playing around with some combination of absolute pathing or the __DIR__ magic constant.

Comment: How do you change permissions? The code I provided works in localhost but the moment it is on my live site it quits working so permissions just seems the logical thing.

Comment: Ok I found the permissions: This is what they are set to

Mode User  Group World
Read x  x               x
Write x  
Execute

Comment: @user3658885 depends on what permissions you are talking about. CHMOD and htaccess files are how i secure files.

Comment: @user3658885 I really don't think it's a file permission issue. http://jollyrogerpcs.com/resources/georgiaAmberLightApplication.pdf  is a valid link that i can open. This implies that it's not a permission issue.

Comment: Is there an alternative code example I can try since the link opens?

Comment: @user3658885 First change your html to     <div id="resources">
    <h1>Pilot Car Resources</h1>
    <table style="width:400px" id="resourcesTable">
      <tr>
       <td>Kansas Handbook</td>
       <td><a href="http://jollyrogerpcs.com/scripts/php/downloadPDF.php?file=/kansasHandbook.pdf ">Download PDF File</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>GA Amber Light Application</td>
       <td><a href="http://jollyrogerpcs.com/scripts/php/downloadPDF.php?file=georgiaAmberLightApplication.pdf">Download PDF File</a></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </div>

Comment: @user3658885 add 'http://' to those href tags. It took them away. HOWEVER this alone will not solve all of your problems. You have more changes to make.